# Class of Surfaces of revolution

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Does exist a kind of surfaces of revolution, in isothermal coordinates (i.e. $E=G$; $F=f=0$, where $E,G,F$ are first fundamental form coefficients, and $e,f,g$ are second fundamental form coefficients) such that $H^2-K=c^2$ (with $H$ nonconstant mean curvature, $K$ nonconstant Gaussian curvature, and $c>0$ constant) ?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The constraints on the first and second fundamental forms are extraneous, in the sense that $H^{2} - K = c^{2}$ is a coordinate-independent condition. Expressing $H^{2} - K = c^{2}$ in terms of the profile of a surface of revolution gives a second-order ODE for the profile. Have you written this down and attempted to show it has/does not have solutions? That is, can you please say where you're stuck?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang: I was doing a work where I have shown that this class of surfaces (i.e. $H^2-K=c^2$, with $c>0$ constant and $H$ nonconstant) cannot be Bonnet's surfaces.. I used isothermal coordinates, but you are right $H^2-K=c^2$ is a coordinate-independent condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the usual differential geometry notation

$$ H^2 - K = c^2; \quad ( (\kappa_1+\kappa_1)/2)^2 -\kappa_1 \kappa_1 =c^2 \rightarrow (\kappa_1 -\kappa_2)  = \pm  2 c $$

there are two particular cases. First

$$  c=0 $$

are spheres

EDITS 1-4:

and second non-zero case is a *class of surfaces*, (shall have to check its name, may be found in book by LP Eisenhart? Blashke? ) which cannot be *fully* determined if you do not further define its character viz., geodesy, normal curvature /asymptotic conditions.

However your question relates to (principal) curvatures only, so we are talking *about their meridians only*.You should be looking at meridians only, I am adding meridians a note in  edit to include meridians of DeLaunay and my ( for want of a better name ..Coiloids)

In the pictures below I added arbitrary disposition of fiber angle relations..

as *geodesics* from a bundle in the first figure and *loxodromes* in the second figure bundle.You should be looking at meridians only in the figures,the extra rotational symmetry build-up is not directly related to your question. The meridians are isolated in what follows..

The first figure is  a torus among a series of periodic *bellows*  $\kappa_1 - \kappa_2 = 2 c =1, $ cuspidal minimum radii are  $ =2.4\,  c > c $

The second figure writes loxodromes $\psi= 1.5 $ on a meridian with negative 
$\kappa_1 - \kappa_2 =-2.4 c $

*Unduloids of DeLaunay and Coiloids*

If $\phi$ is tangent rotation, $u= \cos\phi$,$r$ is radius, $ c\rightarrow 1/c$ ( more comfortable with a physics linear dimension agreement). The ODEs are different and should be given different names. It is quite incorrect to classify or bracket $ y^{\prime\prime}+y =0,\, y^{\prime\prime} - y =0,\, $ together because change of sign in curvature sets them fundamentally apart in Riemannian geometry. Their distinctive ODEs can be written so:

*DeLaunay Unduloids*

$$ \frac{du}{dr} +\frac{u}{r}=\frac{2}{c}$$

Integrates to

$$ u= \frac{r}{c}+\frac{\lambda}{r} $$

$$ \kappa_1= \frac{1}{c}-\frac{\lambda}{r^2} $$

$$ \kappa_2= \frac{1}{c}+\frac{\lambda}{r^2} $$

*Coiloids*

$$ \frac{du}{dr}-\frac{u}{r} = \frac{2}{c}$$

Integrates to

$$ u = \frac{2 r\, \log\,r}{c}+ \lambda\,r $$

$$ \kappa_1= \frac{2(1+\log\,r)}{c}+\lambda\, $$

$$ \kappa_2= \frac{2 \log\,r}{c}+\lambda $$

[image: DeLaunay&Coiloids]

some meridians of the latter class of scalar invariants $ \kappa_1 - \kappa_2= 1/c $

[image: Positive & Negative Curvature Difference Bellows]

*Mohr Circles of curvature*

Three curvatures ( compare stress and curvature tensors) is of fundamental importance. Mohr circles of three types ( H,K,D ) respectively. $D$ accounts for failure stress in mechanics of materials and it is (to me ) comforting to treat it as curvature tensor in its own right.

$$ H^2 - D^2 = K $$

[image: MohrCircless3Types]

If it is a new class to be identified for reference or for referential convenience then the Mohr's circle of curvature of $ \kappa_n $ vs $ \tau_g $ needs to be named ( time being I call it D) and accordingly sketched  to appreciate what remains invariant in this class. $ \kappa_1- \kappa_2 =1/c = D $ is the radius of each of Mohr's circle shown schematically in the third sketch. Mohr's circles of curvature in this $D$ constant case show that any line drawn on rotationally symmetric surface has a common *maximum* geodesic torsion $\pm  \tau_g = D $ as envelope of sliding Mohr circles.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, can you post me the system that you had set?

Comment: as above, hope to post another pic for c < 0

Comment: Thank you very much again!!!!

Comment: thanks a lot for completeness , its very interesring! also for the differential equation of meridian

Comment: I am also fond of DG, shall comment later on apparent lack of a proper name "difference curvature" . Please search for this name available  in your university library  DG books.

Comment: ok, I try to look for..

Comment: thank you again for your precious examples..now I'm looking for "correct" name of this class of surfaces, but, for the moment, I don't find anything..

Comment: I found in this paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/117971?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents that the "formula" $f(H^2-K)$ is called Weingarten relation.. then should try to look something like "constant Weingarten relation Surfaces" or something like that, but at the moment I haven't found anything.

Comment: As per DG book by DJ Struik pp203, (Some Problems and Propositions) any $f(\kappa_1, \kappa_2)=0 $ is a W-surface. Const $H, K, H^2-K =0,\kappa_1/\kappa_2 = $ const $ etc.